# Using exec() to make and assign variables from a text file

Tags: python, string, exec

This question is a follow-up to [the question I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580277/read-values-from-a-file-automatically-creating-variables-to-store-them), which in summary was:

"In python how do I read in parameters from the text file `params.txt`, creating the variables and assigning them the values that are in the file? The contents of the file are (please ignore the auto syntax highlighting, `params.txt` is actually a plain text file):

```
Lx = 512 Ly = 512
g = 400
================ Dissipation =====================
nupower = 8 nu = 0
...[etc]
```

and I want my python script to read the file so that I have Lx, Ly, g, nupower, nu etc available as variables (not keys in a dictionary) with the appropriate values given in `params.txt`. By the way I'm a python novice."

With help, I have come up with the following solution that uses exec():

```
with open('params.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        splitline = line.strip().split(' ')
        for i, word in enumerate(splitline):
            if word == '=':
                exec(splitline[i-1] + splitline[i] + splitline[i+1])
```

This works, e.g. `print(Lx)` returns `512` as expected.

My questions are:

(1) Is this approach safe? Most questions mentioning the `exec()` function have answers that contain dire warnings about its use, and imply that you shouldn't use it unless you really know what you're doing. As mentioned, I'm a novice so I really don't know what I'm doing, so I want to check that I won't be making problems for myself with this solution. The rest of the script does some basic analysis and plotting using the variables read in from this file, and data from other files.

(2) If I want to wrap up the code above in a function, e.g. `read_params()`, is it just a matter of changing the last line to `exec(splitline[i-1] + splitline[i] + splitline[i+1], globals())`? I understand that this causes `exec()` to make the assignments in the global namespace. What I don't understand is whether this is safe, and if not why not. (See above about being a novice!)

Comment: Using `exec()` is generally considered unsafe (a potential security hazard depending on the source of the input). Dynamically creating variables is a poor Python programming practice — although it's possible. See [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables).

Comment: I suggest that you use Python's [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) module to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks martineau and GordonAitchJay, I now understand the security risk (which I'm not worried about in this case because none of this code faces the outside world). But as well as security, if I declare variables using `exec()` like this, is there any 'code-safety' problems to do with how python keeps track of variables, garbage collection, improper use of the stack etc?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) Is this approach safe?

No, it is not safe. If someone can edit/control/replace `params.txt`, they can craft it in such a way to allow arbitrary code execution on the machine running the script.

It really depends where and who will run your Python script, and whether they can modify `params.txt`. If it's just a script run directly on a normal computer by a user, then there's not much to worry about, because they already have access to the machine and can do whatever malicious things they want, without having to do it using your Python script.

> (2) If I want to wrap up the code above in a function, e.g. read_params(), is it just a matter of changing the last line to exec(splitline[i-1] + splitline[i] + splitline[i+1], globals())?

Correct. It doesn't change the fact you can execute arbitrary code.

Suppose this is `params.txt`:

```
Lx = 512 Ly = 512
g = 400
_ = print("""Holy\u0020calamity,\u0020scream\u0020insanity\nAll\u0020you\u0020ever\u0020gonna\u0020be's\nAnother\u0020great\u0020fan\u0020of\u0020me,\u0020break\n""")
_ = exec(f"import\u0020ctypes")
_ = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None,"Releasing\u0020your\u0020uranium\u0020hexaflouride\u0020in\u00203...\u00202...\u00201...","Warning!",0)
================ Dissipation =====================
nupower = 8 nu = 0
```

And this is your script:

```py
def read_params():
    with open('params.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            splitline = line.strip().split(' ')
            for i, word in enumerate(splitline):
                if word == '=':
                    exec(splitline[i-1] + splitline[i] + splitline[i+1], globals())

read_params()
```

As you can see, it has correctly assigned your variables, but it has also called `print`, imported the `ctypes` library, and has then presented you with a dialog box letting you know that your little backyard enrichment facility has been thwarted.

As *martineau* suggested, you can use [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser). You'd have to modify `params.txt` so there is only one variable per line.

tl;dr: Using `exec` is unsafe, and not best practice, but that doesn't matter if your Python script will only be run on a normal computer by users you trust. They can already do malicious things, simply by having access to the computer as a normal user.

---

> Is there an alternative to configparser?

I'm not sure. With your use-case, I don't think you have much to worry about. Just roll your own.

This is similar to some of the answers in your other question, but is uses [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and updates the `globals` dictionary so you can directly use the variables as you want to.

`params.txt`:

```
Lx = 512 Ly = 512
g = 400
================ Dissipation =====================
nupower = 8 nu = 0
alphapower = -0 alpha = 0
================ Timestepping =========================
SOMEFLAG = 1
SOMEOTHERFLAG = 4
dt = 2e-05
some_dict = {"key":[1,2,3]}
print = "builtins_can't_be_rebound"
```

Script:

```py
import ast

def read_params():
    '''Reads the params file and updates the globals dict.'''
    _globals = globals()
    reserved = dir(_globals['__builtins__'])
    with open('params.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            tokens = line.strip().split(' ')
            zipped_tokens = zip(tokens, tokens[1:], tokens[2:])
            for prev_token, curr_token, next_token in zipped_tokens:
                if curr_token == '=' and prev_token not in reserved:
                    #print(prev_token, curr_token, next_token)
                    try:
                        _globals[prev_token] = ast.literal_eval(next_token)
                    except (SyntaxError, ValueError) as e:
                        print(f'Cannot eval "{next_token}". {e}. Continuing...')

read_params()

# We can now use the variables as expected
Lx += Ly
print(Lx, Ly, SOMEFLAG, some_dict)
```

Output:

```
1024 512 1 {'key': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and the unexpected hiphop (with the extremely unexpected sample that I last heard on an Anthrax album back in the mid 90s!)

In principle I don't have access to the code that writes `params.txt`. Is there an alternative to `configparser`? Or in that case would the solution be to read in `params.txt`, check for the input being as expected, and then writing a config file in the correct format and then reading it back in? Seems a long way round to do a simple task!

Comment: haha no worries. You're right, doing that seems cumbersome. The `read_params` function I wrote should do the job. At least it works with the small bit of `params.txt` you posted.

Comment: @jms547: Just FYI, the [`ConfigObj`](https://pypi.org/project/configobj/) module is a very good alternative to `configparser`.